# javascript open new tab and cannot get the tags and attributes from the new tab, but only get null

Tags: javascript, dom, properties, onload

I am a newbie in Javascript. Using javascript, I want to open a new tab with onload method and get the desired tag from the new tab to manipulate, but it does not work. How can I fix this?

When I am on any google search page, I want to open http://google.com and insert some texts in the search box through Javascript automatically. But it issues "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null"

I wanted to see if the parent tab can access the google.com searchbox through console.log(""), but it shows me just null.

From any of google search result page,  I tried to enter some texts on the google.com search box.

```
win = window.open("https://google.com/");

function searchbox() {
    win.document.querySelector('input.gLFyf.gsfi').value="aaaa";
};
win.onload = searchbox();
```

After the new google.com tab opened, the console results is like,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at searchbox (<anonymous>:4:54)
    at <anonymous>:6:14
searchbox @ VM456:4
(anonymous) @ VM456:6
```

When I try this,

```
win = window.open("https://google.com/");

function searchbox() {
    console.log(win.document.querySelector('input.gLFyf.gsfi'));
};
win.onload = searchbox();
```

the result is null.

I do not know why it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the DOM of a newly-opened window, if you used `window.open()` to open it, unless its URL is of the same origin as your page (so - not Google ).

Here's a quote from [`window.open`'s documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

> **Return Value**
>
> A WindowProxy object, which is basically a thin wrapper for the Window
>   object representing the newly created window, and has all its features
>   available. If the window couldn't be opened, the returned value is
>   instead null. The returned reference can be used to access properties
>   and methods of the new window **as long as it complies with
>   Same-origin policy security requirements**.

Comment: Thnks for the answer. But I thought the google search result page has same origin URL with https://google.com since google search result URL starts like https://www.google.com/search?q=.... Do I have lack of basic knowledge of same URL origin?

Comment: Under what url is your code running? I doubt you run it on google.com.

Comment: I ran the js code on any of google search result page such as 
https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=rE9CXbCrNPCGr7wP8cCV2AM&q=abcd&oq=abcd&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.612.1680..2585...0.0..0.163.695.1j5......0....1..gws-wiz.....0.Dk2pXhlMXDg&ved=0ahUKEwiwsf2h0eDjAhVww4sBHXFgBTsQ4dUDCAU&uact=5
This is abcd result page